# Invisible elements when updating ion-list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ***ion-list*** where the items is a ***div*** containing several elements to create a card component. The list is populated using ***ng-repeat***. When the array is static, the views are rendered as they should, but when the array is updated, the elements are added(the elements below the list are pushed down), but they are not visible. I tried using `$scope.$apply()` as many suggested, but no luck.

Help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Template:

```
                <div class="item item-avatar">
                    <img src="img/arya.jpg" id="my-avatar">
                    <h2 id="my-time">{{i.Name}}</h2>
                    <p id="my-eta">Arriving in {{i.Bus}} minutes</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
                    <a class="tab-item" data-ink-color="#336699" data-ink-opacity="0.5" ng-click="aaa()">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-alarm"></i> Alarm
                    </a>
                    <a class="tab-item" data-ink-color="#336699" data-ink-opacity="0.5">
                        <i class="icon ion-android-call"></i> Call School
                    </a>
                    <a class="tab-item" data-ink-color="#336699" data-ink-opacity="0.5">
                        <i class="icon ion-location"></i> Track
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('ChildrenListCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $ionicModal, $ionicPopover, $timeout, $state, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion) {


ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
$scope.children = [];


$scope.items = [
    {
        "Name": "Sameer",
        "Bus": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sameer",
        "Bus": 1
    }];

console.log("ChildrenListCtrl loaded");

var reset = function () {

    var inClass = document.querySelectorAll('.in');
    for (var i = 0; i < inClass.length; i++) {
        inClass[i].classList.remove('in');
        inClass[i].removeAttribute('style');
    }
    var done = document.querySelectorAll('.done');
    for (var i = 0; i < done.length; i++) {
        done[i].classList.remove('done');
        done[i].removeAttribute('style');
    }
    var ionList = document.getElementsByTagName('ion-list');
    for (var i = 0; i < ionList.length; i++) {
        var toRemove = ionList[i].className;
        if (/animate-/.test(toRemove)) {
            ionList[i].className = ionList[i].className.replace(/(?:^|\s)animate-\S*(?:$|\s)/, '');
        }
    }
};

var delay = 5;

$scope.ripple = function () {
    reset();
    document.getElementsByTagName('ion-list')[0].className += ' animate-ripple';
    $timeout(function () {
        ionicMaterialMotion.ripple();
    }, delay);
};

$scope.fadeSlideInRight = function () {
    reset();
    document.getElementsByTagName('ion-list')[0].className += ' animate-fade-slide-in-right';
    $timeout(function () {
        ionicMaterialMotion.fadeSlideInRight();
    }, delay);
};

$scope.fadeSlideIn = function () {
    reset();
    document.getElementsByTagName('ion-list')[0].className += ' animate-fade-slide-in';
    $timeout(function () {
        ionicMaterialMotion.fadeSlideIn();
    }, delay);
};

$scope.blinds = function () {
    reset();
    document.getElementsByTagName('ion-list')[0].className += ' animate-blinds';
    $timeout(function () {
        ionicMaterialMotion.blinds(); // ionic.material.motion.blinds(); //ionicMaterialMotion
    }, delay);
};

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromParams, toParams) {
    if (toState.name == "app.children-list") {
        console.log("Animating....");
        $scope.blinds();
    }
});


$scope.aaa = function () {
    $scope.items.push(
            {
                "Name": "Sameer",
                "Bus": 1
            })
};
$scope.$apply();
```

});

I call the `aaa()` function to add an item to the array. Hope this helps.

Comment: do you have code example? jsfiddle/plnkr to understand the problem?

Comment: can you simulate it in plunker so we can help you.

Comment: It's a full ionic project with a lot of libraries; it seems that I can't upload files to jsfiddle/plnkr. I'll update my question by adding the code.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it. The animate function should be called explicitly after the array is updated Thanks anyway!